# Reducing APK size by re-zipping its content

Tags: android, apk

I have a pretty large apk file, and I'm trying to reduce its size. 
Already used all the common techniques, such as Proguard and image compression. Still, the apk is quite large - about 25mb.

[Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/APK_(file_format)) says that:

> APK files are a type of archive file, specifically in zip format
>   packages based on the JAR file format, with .apk as the filename
>   extension.

I've recently noticed that if I'll unzip the apk (Android Studio's artifact output), re-zip it using 7-Zip and sign it, then the size magically decreases by 2.5mb (to ~22.5mb). I'm able to upload it to Play, install and run it without an issue.

And here're my questions:

- Is there any data that wiped during unzip & rezip process?
- If ***no***, why aapt (the one that Android Studio uses) packages files
  in so inefficient manner?
- If ***yes***, what data is being wiped (please post some links where I
  could read more about it)? What could go wrong if
  I'll use this method?

Thanks!

---

**Edit [5/13/2015]:**

Compressing the APK contents worked well for me. However, I had to be cautious with raw resources (typically placed under res/raw). For example, invoking [Resources#openRawResourceFd](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Resources.html#openRawResourceFd(int)) with a compressed resource as parameter will end with the following exception:

> java.io.FileNotFoundException: This file can not be opened as a file
>   descriptor; it is probably compressed

Therefore, remember to exclude raw resources from compression.

Comment: 1. Different compression/compaction algorithms may be more or less efficient depending on the actual files being put into an archive. 2. Why are you so concerned that you can get a 10% reduction in APK file size? It's not exactly a huge reduction - the Facebook app, for example, is close to 26MB 3. If you're concerned about data / components being wiped, why don't you just test things yourself? Just use the two different methods, unzip the two variations of the apk files and then run a file compare on each of the files.

Comment: @Squonk 3 - I have verified that no files being changed/removed. I'm more concerned about a (possible) metadata injections, that later used by Android on end-user's device.

Comment: @Squonk Well, if your apk is close to the 50 MB limit (say, 54 MB), a 10% reduction in size could make the difference between being published or not.

Comment: @AlexLipov : An APK is, quite literally, a ZIP file - I've never seen evidence to the contrary or there is any 'hidden' metadata. You've tested your theory - you were able to upload to Google Play and install and run without problem. I've published a few apps and trust me - if Google didn't like what you'd uploaded then it would fail at that point. Being able to install and run basically seals the deal - whether it's a good thing to do or not is another matter. Compression techniques have a history of licensing/intellectual property issues etc. Perhaps aapt just goes with a simple approach.

Comment: @FrankN.Stein : Sure, I get your point but with something well within the limits of APK size, i.e., 25MB with a 2.5MB reduction, there seems little point in expending the extra time / effort. In your example, what if your next APK grows from 54MB to 56MB or 60MB? At this point you're going to have to look at expansion files anyway.

Comment: @Squonk Yes, sure. You are right in **most cases** ;) But, still, on a **limit case** (50.x to 54.9 MB) it `could be` a valid option. For less than 50 MB there's no such a big gain. For 56+ MB you'd sure use an expansion file.

Comment: If you are going to use your own tools to create the apk file, make sure to run `zipalign` afterward you have compressed and signed it - failure to do so may not make the app un-runnable, but may make the result require substantially more memory at runtime.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I'm able to upload it to Play, install and run it without an issue.

Only on the devices that you tried. I suspect, for example, that you did not try an API Level 1 device.

> Is there any data that wiped during unzip & rezip process?

We have no way of answering that question. The only person who can answer that question is you, as you are the one who did your specific "unzip & rezip process". You should be able to analyze your two ZIP files and see where the differences are, such as higher compression ratios on certain file types, files that got lost by the way you ran your "rezip process", etc.

In general, the only thing that should be lost would be any zipalign-ing, if you did not reapply that yourself.

> If no, why aapt (the one that Android Studio uses) packages files in so inefficient manner?

Size is not the only consideration. Speed of access is another, as many things (e.g., resources, assets) are kept in the APK file and read out of there on the fly as needed. Memory consumption for the decompression logic is yet another consideration.

Android devices, particularly early ones, have many constraints, disk space being but one of them. Even though some of these constraints have been relaxed as hardware has advanced, the build tools are dedicated to backwards compatibility -- you should be able to write an app today that can run on an API Level 1 device, for example. That puts constraints on the *tools* in terms of how they can change over time.

> What could go wrong if I'll use this method?

Your app may not work on Android devices, where their runtimes are set up making certain assumptions about the APK ZIP compression algorithms use. Ideally, your app will run fine everywhere. At minimum, you would want to test your app on every API level that you support -- older API levels may be somewhat more likely to "cut corners" and make assumptions that your approach will invalidate.

Answer (score 5):

Assuming you are forcing 7zip to use its zip compatible mode (`-tzip`) then this is an entirely valid operation (though as @CommonsWare notes, there is a tiny possibility that you are opening yourself up to some buggy implementations of the zip unpacking routine on some phones).

The reason that you are able to get a size reduction are twofold:

- 7zip has a better compressor, that uses more CPU on the compression to come up with a perfectly compatible but more compressed representation
- aapt which is traditionally used to do the compression/packaging of the Android file has a long list of filetypes (such as jpg, png, mp3) that it simply does not try to compress, on the grounds that these filetypes already have internal compression.  Even so, there's often a few percent gain to be had by compressing them inside the apk file

Answer (score 1):

```
7z a -tzip output1.zip -mx9 -r *.*
```

this sequence of parameters worked for me for 7zipping

- a - add to archive
- output1.zip - output name
- mx9 - no idea
- -r - recurse subdirs
- *.* - all files

The answer from roj didn't quite work for me, 7zip was very picky about parameter ordering

Comment: I think `mx9` sets the compression level

Answer (score 0):

1. Only sign the apk with the "V1 (Jar Signature)" option when creating the apk. This is an option on the dialog when generating a signed apk in Android Studio. Read the caution here, https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/zipalign.
2. Unzip the apk to a folder, for example app-release.
3. Go to a command prompt in the folder app-release.
4. Then re-zip:

   "C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe" a -tzip -mx9 -r app-release.zip *.*
5. Then align:

   "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\build-tools\30.0.0\zipalign.exe" -f -v 4 app-release.zip app-release.apk
6. Then verify alignment:

   "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\build-tools\30.0.0\zipalign.exe" -c -v 4 app-release.apk

Comment: APK signature v1 is deprecated. Device running Android 11 (API level 30) you need at least v2 or v3.