# Why size of apk is so low?

Tags: java, android, c, apk, executable

I have an android project with total size 280 MB. But when I build it, the apk created is just 6 Mb. How is such a compression factor achieved. I have many third party libraries and resources in my project.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Reducing android app (apk) size](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25101534/reducing-android-app-apk-size)

Answer (score 1):

The most direct answer is that you are compiling an APK, not compressing it. You are changing the nature of the content, not making the content smaller.

Lots of things happen during a compile that can reduce the size of the pre-compiled content.

Here is an explanation of the compile process for C++ here on SO that is pretty good. APK compilation is different but the ideas are largely the same.

[How does the compilation/linking process work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6264249/how-does-the-compilation-linking-process-work)

here is one that is more specific to the APK compile process. I'm not familiar enough with that process to know how accurate the article is but it seems decent.

http://www.alittlemadness.com/2010/06/07/understanding-the-android-build-process/