# Android vector compatibility

Tags: android, vector, drawable

I'd like to start using vectors for the icons with in the apps I do, but not sure how to deal with the compatibility

I'm not interested in any of the third party compat libraries and happy to wait for googles version (Mentioned here [VectorDrawable - is it available somehow for pre-Lollipop versions of Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26548354/vectordrawable-is-it-available-somehow-to-pre-lollipop-versions-of-android)).

So basically for now I'm happy to continue to have the images per resolution as well as an additional for > Lollipop. If the device is higher than 21 it will use the vector otherwise it will fall back to the standard png's.

I can have the vector in a drawable-v21 folder, but the drawable-[dpi] folder takes precedence over the version, meaning the vector isn't used.

I'm hoping the vector is used so that when the compat comes available I can simply delete all the png's and know the vectors will be ok as I have been able to test them on a device running Lollipop.

Comment: @JaiSoni now compare your link and OP's link...

Comment: Actual info on how to use appcompat vectors - http://stackoverflow.com/q/40678947/7045114

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From Android 5.0 (API level 21) you can use vector drawable in your app. You can use new Android Studio tool called: Vector Asset Studio. It handles PNG making for older versions automatically. See link below for a complete explanation:

[Vector Asset Studio](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/vector-asset-studio.html)

Answer (score 2):

Now google released [Android Support Library 23.2](http://android-developers.blogspot.in/2016/02/android-support-library-232.html) Support Vector Drawables and Animated Vector Drawables !

```
 // Gradle Plugin 2.0+  
 android {  
   defaultConfig {  
     vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true  
    }  
 }
```

> **Note:**
>
> **- Vector images all the way back to API 7 (Android 2.1 Eclair).**
>
> **- Animated vectors are a bit more limited, going only as far back
>   as API 11**

Answer (score 2):

In order to have backwards compatibility for Vector Drawables here is the following configuration I used for API Level pre-20 devices.

**build.gradle**

```
vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true

dependencies{classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.1.2'}
```

**Activity**

onCreate > AppCompatDelegate.setCompatVectorFromResourcesEnabled(true);

**XML ImageView**

```
app:srcCompat="@drawable/vector"
```

**Programmatic ImageView**

```
imageView.setBackgroundResource(R.vector);
```

**vector.xml**

```
<vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:width="30dp"
        android:height="20dp"
        android:viewportHeight="20.0"
        android:viewportWidth="30.0">
    <path
        android:fillColor="#4C5F70"
        android:pathData="DATA_HERE"
        android:strokeColor="#00000000"
        android:strokeWidth="1"/>
</vector>
```

Answer (score 1):

With Android Support Library 23.2, 
VectorDrawables are now supported from API level 7 onwards and AnimatedVectorDrawables from API level 11 so.

So now you can use

`app:srcCompat`

instead of

`app:src`

for using `VectorDrawable`s with backward compatibility.

Comment: Nice update. Do you have a link to the details around this. Has google put up any details regarding it.

Answer (score 1):

if you use SRC, then use this:

```
AppCompatDelegate.setCompatVectorFromResourcesEnabled(true);
```

You don't need to add that line in every activity, if you added it once in the Application class it will work as well. Like this:

```
public class App extends Application {

static {

    AppCompatDelegate.setCompatVectorFromResourcesEnabled(true);
}
```

REMEMBER: You still need to have enabled the use of the support library in app level gradle:

```
android {

  defaultConfig {

    vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true

  }

}
```

Inside xml use:

```
<ImageView
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_add" />
```

When you want to use vector drawable as drawableTop, bottom, right ,left then used LayerDrawable otherwise it will crash on devices lower than 5.0

```
<level-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/search"/>
</level-list>
```

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT:** This was an interim fix until Android studio 1.4 was released. There is no longer a need for this. See Ka Developer's answer instead

Found a solution that while not brilliant does work.

You need to create a lollypop drawables folder for each of the dpi folders and add the same vector to each folder.

Eg create the folders

drawable-hdpi-v21

drawable-xhdpi-v21

drawable-xxhdpi-v21

drawable-xxxhdpi-v21