# android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException API Level 19

Tags: android, api, menu, apk

Someone had any idea why when I tested my apk on android 7 perfect, tested on 5 perfect... but if I test on 4.4.2 crash when load icons from drawable... this is the code where my apk crash:

```
Drawable drawable = null;
        Integer id_icon = 0;
        if (materia.getIcon() != null) {
            id_icon = getResources().getIdentifier(materia.getIcon(), "drawable", "com.package");
        } else {
            Integer size = materia.getTopics().size();
            if (size >= 1 && size <= 9) {
                id_icon = getResources().getIdentifier("ic_filter_" + size.toString() + "_black", "drawable", "com.package");
            } else {
                if (size > 9) {
                    id_icon = getResources().getIdentifier("ic_filter_9_plus_black", "drawable", "com.package");
                }
            }
        }
//This line is where throw the exception.... but why??
        if (id_icon > 0) drawable = (Drawable) getResources().getDrawable(id_icon);
        MenuItem menuItem = sm.add(R.id.list_materiales, Menu.NONE, i, Html.fromHtml(materia.getMaterial())).setCheckable(true).setChecked(false);
        menuItem.setIcon(drawable);
        storageKeys.addKeyMaterial(materia.getKey());
```

this is my gradle conf:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'realm-android'

android {
   compileSdkVersion 26
   defaultConfig {
       applicationId "com.package"
       minSdkVersion 19
       targetSdkVersion 19
       versionCode 1
       versionName "1.0"
       vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
   }
    buildTypes {
       release {
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'),  'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
       targetCompatibility 1.8
       sourceCompatibility 1.8
    }
}
dependencies {
   implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
   implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:26.1.0'
   implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:26.1.0'
   //
   implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
   implementation 'com.android.support:design:26.1.0'
   implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'  'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:+'
   implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:26.1.0'
   implementation 'com.android.support:support-vector-drawable:26.1.0'
}
```

Thanks on advance.. and sorry for my poor English...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you using vector drawables?

if so refer to this post.

[vector drawables on pre lollipop crash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36867298/using-android-vector-drawables-on-pre-lollipop-crash)

Otherwise you should post the error message.