# Android use linear gradient in api 16

Tags: android, xml, android-vectordrawable

I have an XML drawable which used linear gradient, my app has minimal API 16 but the [linear gradient](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/VectorDrawable.html) can only be used on API 24 and above, is there any way I can use to use this drawable in API 16?

```
<gradient android:endX="34688.73750883036"
            android:endY="-5838.021014985162"
            android:startX="28414.035716727485"
            android:startY="-2446.8302221162985" android:type="linear"/>
```

Comment: Use appcompat, I think it covers that

Comment: @Zoe, I use method from this linke:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36867298/using-android-vector-drawables-on-pre-lollipop-crash?noredirect=1&lq=1, but the drawable is still broken