# Which option is better fro game about tapping an image fast: SetOnClicklistener or OnClick from Design view?

Tags: java, android, google-play, google-play-console

I have mobile game already in Google Play Store, it´s about tapping a circle which is moving randomly through the screen and it goes faster every second (limit is - 300 milliseconds). everytime is tapped, it reproduces a very quick sound (indicating a point).

The problem is that in my google play console I can see there have been crashes.

'Resources$NotFoundException
in game.FailedTap' (FailedTap is function set by OnClick, that only reproduces a sound indicating you lost a live.)

Comment: I THINK is because the sound overlaps but I'm not sure

Comment: The title and the question ask two different questions. :) But it could even be that both ways produce identical bytecode in the end. As for the crash: you should show the code in `FailedTap()`. Now we don't know how you are playing the sound. Maybe it's a problem with the `MediaPlayer` state? Maybe not.

Comment: My very personal opinion: I really HATE to have code-related parts inside of the design part.

Comment: Could you post your code as well as the full stack trace that you got from Google Play console?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [App sometimes crashes with Resources$NotFoundException after switching to android app bundle distribution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52469914/app-sometimes-crashes-with-resourcesnotfoundexception-after-switching-to-androi)