# Image in all folders, but still getting ResouceNotFound exception

Tags: android, android-drawable

I have 3 images in my login screen which I have kept in drawable-hdpi, drawable-mdpi, drawable-xhdpi, drawable-xxhdpi and in drawable-xxxhdpi.

I am not getting crash in any of the testing devices but getting this crash on crashlytics :

```
Fatal Exception: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x7f08015f
       at android.content.res.ResourcesImpl.getValue + 216(ResourcesImpl.java:216)
       at android.content.res.Resources.getValue + 1330(Resources.java:1330)
       at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager.createDrawableIfNeeded + 235(AppCompatDrawableManager.java:235)
       at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager.getDrawable + 200(AppCompatDrawableManager.java:200)
       at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager.getDrawable + 191(AppCompatDrawableManager.java:191)
       at android.support.v7.content.res.AppCompatResources.getDrawable + 102(AppCompatResources.java:102)
       at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageHelper.setImageResource + 86(AppCompatImageHelper.java:86)
       at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView.setImageResource + 94(AppCompatImageView.java:94)
       at com.sharesmile.share.login.LoginImagesFragment.onCreateView + 56(LoginImagesFragment.java:56)
       at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView + 2439(Fragment.java:2439)
       at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState + 1460(FragmentManager.java:1460)
       at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveFragmentToExpectedState + 1784(FragmentManager.java:1784)
       at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState + 1852(FragmentManager.java:1852)
       at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.executeOps + 802(BackStackRecord.java:802)
       at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOps + 2625(FragmentManager.java:2625)
       at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOpsTogether + 2411(FragmentManager.java:2411)
       at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.removeRedundantOperationsAndExecute + 2366(FragmentManager.java:2366)
       at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execSingleAction + 2243(FragmentManager.java:2243)
       at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.commitNowAllowingStateLoss + 654(BackStackRecord.java:654)
       at android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter.finishUpdate + 146(FragmentPagerAdapter.java:146)
       at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate + 1244(ViewPager.java:1244)
       at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate + 1092(ViewPager.java:1092)
       at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.onMeasure + 1622(ViewPager.java:1622)
       at android.view.View.measure + 23265(View.java:23265)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins + 6928(ViewGroup.java:6928)
       at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout + 1514(LinearLayout.java:1514)
       at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical + 806(LinearLayout.java:806)
       at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure + 685(LinearLayout.java:685)
       at android.view.View.measure + 23265(View.java:23265)
       at android.widget.RelativeLayout.measureChildHorizontal + 715(RelativeLayout.java:715)
       at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onMeasure + 461(RelativeLayout.java:461)
       at android.view.View.measure + 23265(View.java:23265)
       at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical + 958(LinearLayout.java:958)
       at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure + 685(LinearLayout.java:685)
       at android.view.View.measure + 23265(View.java:23265)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins + 6928(ViewGroup.java:6928)
       at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure + 185(FrameLayout.java:185)
       at android.support.v7.widget.ContentFrameLayout.onMeasure + 143(ContentFrameLayout.java:143)
       at android.view.View.measure + 23265(View.java:23265)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins + 6928(ViewGroup.java:6928)
       at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout + 1514(LinearLayout.java:1514)
       at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical + 806(LinearLayout.java:806)
       at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure + 685(LinearLayout.java:685)
       at android.view.View.measure + 23265(View.java:23265)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins + 6928(ViewGroup.java:6928)
       at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure + 185(FrameLayout.java:185)
       at android.view.View.measure + 23265(View.java:23265)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins + 6928(ViewGroup.java:6928)
       at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout + 1514(LinearLayout.java:1514)
       at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical + 806(LinearLayout.java:806)
       at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure + 685(LinearLayout.java:685)
       at android.view.View.measure + 23265(View.java:23265)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins + 6928(ViewGroup.java:6928)
       at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure + 185(FrameLayout.java:185)
       at com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.onMeasure + 898(DecorView.java:898)
       at android.view.View.measure + 23265(View.java:23265)
       at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure + 2873(ViewRootImpl.java:2873)
       at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy + 1910(ViewRootImpl.java:1910)
       at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals + 2165(ViewRootImpl.java:2165)
       at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal + 1779(ViewRootImpl.java:1779)
       at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run + 7800(ViewRootImpl.java:7800)
       at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run + 911(Choreographer.java:911)
       at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks + 723(Choreographer.java:723)
       at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame + 658(Choreographer.java:658)
       at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run + 897(Choreographer.java:897)
       at android.os.Handler.handleCallback + 789(Handler.java:789)
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage + 98(Handler.java:98)
       at android.os.Looper.loop + 164(Looper.java:164)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.main + 6938(ActivityThread.java:6938)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
       at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run + 327(Zygote.java:327)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main + 1374(ZygoteInit.java:1374)
```

Since the image is present in all folders don't know where is it crashing/going wrong.

Comment: are there still ldpi devices out there?

Comment: is tvdpi a separate value entirely?

Comment: add `drawable-nodpi` folder and give it a try

Comment: @njzk2 not sure about that though about ldpi. for tvdpi our app does not support tv mode.

Comment: What is at `LoginImagesFragment.java:56` ?

Comment: Show us code, how you using that drawables.

Comment: Probably duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52469914/app-sometimes-crashes-with-resourcesnotfoundexception-after-switching-to-androi/52474885#52474885