# ResourceNotFoundException for drawable at launch

Tags: android, android-layout, drawable, android-drawable, android-viewbinding

**Problem**

Sometimes a crash caused by a `ResourceNotFoundException` is reported to me. This exception is caused at the launch of my app : the app seems to doesn't get a drawable resource in my first screen.

**Environment**

My drawable is a `png` and exists in `mdpi`, `hdpi`, `xhdpi`, `xxhdpi` and `xxxhdpi`. I'm using `View Binding` and `Fragment` to get my layout and the id of the drawable is specified in my `xml`

**Side notes**

I don't know if it's because of the first needed drawable or if all my drawables are absent, because it crashes at launch.

This exception happens rarely but enough to be observed, recently it happened on a Pixel 4 and a Galaxy A20s. I have personally never been able to reproduce this error.

**Question**

Is it possible that `Play Store` doesn't give drawables when a user downloads my app ? How can I be sure that drawables are presents in my app ?

**Log**

Here are log that I receive :

```
Caused by android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #25 in xx.xxx.xxx:layout/fragment_home: Error inflating class ImageView
```

and

```
Caused by android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x7f0800c7
       at android.content.res.ResourcesImpl.getValue(ResourcesImpl.java:237)
       at android.content.res.Resources.getValue(Resources.java:1428)
       at androidx.appcompat.widget.ResourceManagerInternal.createDrawableIfNeeded(ResourceManagerInternal.java:176)
       at androidx.appcompat.widget.ResourceManagerInternal.getDrawable(ResourceManagerInternal.java:141)
       at androidx.appcompat.widget.ResourceManagerInternal.getDrawable(ResourceManagerInternal.java:132)
       at androidx.appcompat.content.res.AppCompatResources.getDrawable(AppCompatResources.java:104)
       at androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageHelper.loadFromAttributes(AppCompatImageHelper.java:63)
       at androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageView.<init>(AppCompatImageView.java:82)
       at androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageView.<init>(AppCompatImageView.java:69)
       at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatViewInflater.createImageView(AppCompatViewInflater.java:199)
       at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatViewInflater.createView(AppCompatViewInflater.java:119)
       at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.createView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:1551)
       at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.onCreateView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:1602)
       at android.view.LayoutInflater$FactoryMerger.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:240)
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.tryCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:1059)
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:995)
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:959)
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:1121)
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:1082)
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:1124)
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:1082)
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:1124)
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:1082)
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:680)
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:532)
       at xx.xxx.xxx.databinding.FragmentHomeBinding.inflate(FragmentHomeBinding.java:125)
       at xx.xxx.xxx.databinding.FragmentHomeBinding.inflate(FragmentHomeBinding.java:119)
       at xx.xxx.xxx.fragments.home.HomeFragment.onCreateView(HomeFragment.kt:52)
       at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:2699)
       at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStateManager.createView(FragmentStateManager.java:320)
       at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1199)
       at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1368)
       at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.moveFragmentToExpectedState(FragmentManager.java:1446)
       at androidx.fragment.app.BackStackRecord.executeOps(BackStackRecord.java:442)
       at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.executeOps(FragmentManager.java:2181)
       at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.executeOpsTogether(FragmentManager.java:2004)
       at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.removeRedundantOperationsAndExecute(FragmentManager.java:1959)
       at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.execSingleAction(FragmentManager.java:1830)
       at androidx.fragment.app.BackStackRecord.commitNow(BackStackRecord.java:297)
       at androidx.viewpager2.adapter.FragmentStateAdapter.placeFragmentInViewHolder(FragmentStateAdapter.java:341)
       at androidx.viewpager2.adapter.FragmentStateAdapter.onViewAttachedToWindow(FragmentStateAdapter.java:276)
       at androidx.viewpager2.adapter.FragmentStateAdapter.onViewAttachedToWindow(FragmentStateAdapter.java:67)
       at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchChildAttached(RecyclerView.java:7556)
       at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$5.addView(RecyclerView.java:860)
       at androidx.recyclerview.widget.ChildHelper.addView(ChildHelper.java:107)
       at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$LayoutManager.addViewInt(RecyclerView.java:8601)
       at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$LayoutManager.addView(RecyclerView.java:8559)
       at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$LayoutManager.addView(RecyclerView.java:8547)
       at androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager.layoutChunk(LinearLayoutManager.java:1641)
       at androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager.fill(LinearLayoutManager.java:1587)
       at androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager.onLayoutChildren(LinearLayoutManager.java:665)
       at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayoutStep2(RecyclerView.java:4134)
       at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView.onMeasure(RecyclerView.java:3540)
       at android.view.View.measure(View.java:25466)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChild(ViewGroup.java:6928)
       at androidx.viewpager2.widget.ViewPager2.onMeasure(ViewPager2.java:498)
       at android.view.View.measure(View.java:25466)
       at androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout$Measurer.measure(ConstraintLayout.java:763)
       at androidx.constraintlayout.solver.widgets.analyzer.BasicMeasure.measure(BasicMeasure.java:426)
       at androidx.constraintlayout.solver.widgets.analyzer.BasicMeasure.measureChildren(BasicMeasure.java:105)
       at androidx.constraintlayout.solver.widgets.analyzer.BasicMeasure.solverMeasure(BasicMeasure.java:247)
       at androidx.constraintlayout.solver.widgets.ConstraintWidgetContainer.measure(ConstraintWidgetContainer.java:117)
       at androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout.resolveSystem(ConstraintLayout.java:1532)
       at androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout.onMeasure(ConstraintLayout.java:1607)
       at android.view.View.measure(View.java:25466)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6957)
       at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:194)
       at android.view.View.measure(View.java:25466)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6957)
       at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:194)
       at android.view.View.measure(View.java:25466)
       at androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout$Measurer.measure(ConstraintLayout.java:763)
       at androidx.constraintlayout.solver.widgets.analyzer.BasicMeasure.measure(BasicMeasure.java:426)
       at androidx.constraintlayout.solver.widgets.analyzer.BasicMeasure.measureChildren(BasicMeasure.java:105)
       at androidx.constraintlayout.solver.widgets.analyzer.BasicMeasure.solverMeasure(BasicMeasure.java:247)
       at androidx.constraintlayout.solver.widgets.ConstraintWidgetContainer.measure(ConstraintWidgetContainer.java:117)
       at androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout.resolveSystem(ConstraintLayout.java:1532)
       at androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout.onMeasure(ConstraintLayout.java:1607)
       at android.view.View.measure(View.java:25466)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6957)
       at androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout.onMeasureChild(CoordinatorLayout.java:760)
       at androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout.onMeasure(CoordinatorLayout.java:833)
       at android.view.View.measure(View.java:25466)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6957)
       at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:194)
       at androidx.appcompat.widget.ContentFrameLayout.onMeasure(ContentFrameLayout.java:146)
       at android.view.View.measure(View.java:25466)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6957)
       at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1552)
       at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:842)
       at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:721)
       at android.view.View.measure(View.java:25466)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6957)
       at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:194)
       at android.view.View.measure(View.java:25466)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6957)
       at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1552)
       at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:842)
       at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:721)
       at android.view.View.measure(View.java:25466)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6957)
       at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:194)
       at com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.onMeasure(DecorView.java:747)
       at android.view.View.measure(View.java:25466)
       at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:3397)
       at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:2228)
       at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:2486)
       at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1952)
       at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:8171)
       at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:972)
       at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:796)
       at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:731)
       at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:957)
       at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:938)
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7656)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
       at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:947)
```

**XML**

This `ImageView`concerned :

```
<ImageView
  android:id="@+id/first_image"
  android:layout_width="0dp"
  android:layout_height="0dp"
  android:adjustViewBounds="true"
  android:baselineAlignBottom="true"
  android:contentDescription="@null"
  android:cropToPadding="true"
  android:scaleType="centerCrop"
  app:srcCompat="@drawable/home_1"
  app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="1:1"
  app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
  app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
  app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"/>
```

The `id` is correct, but like I said I don't know if the issue is caused by this drawable especially or if all my drawables are concerned and the app crashes at first `ImageView`

Comment: Can you share some logs or code?

Comment: To check resources: you can open any APK as compressed archive and check "res" folder as you do when developing an App. However without any log or error we cannot help you very much.....

Comment: I've added some logs ! I haven't been able to reproduce that issue, so maybe the issue come from the ```Play Store``` ?

Comment: please share your fragment_home.xml. There is something wrong with your imageview in line 25. I thing your using wrong imageview id.

Comment: put the drawable in default `drawable` also.

Comment: Did you ever find out what happened or a way to fix it? I'm facing the same rare crash report on startup, coincidentally also with a Galaxy A device.

Comment: @moertel Unfortunately no, it always happens, very rarely but always

Comment: @Ady I continued the search yesterday and found this response by a (former?) Google employee. The reason seems to be users trying to load the app outside of the Play Store. As AABs consist of multiple ABKs, users can get incomplete resources this way. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52469914/app-sometimes-crashes-with-resourcesnotfoundexception-after-switching-to-androi/52474885#52474885

Comment: @moertel Oh, so if someone has this problem, it's their fault! Thank you for your help!

Comment: @Ady you're welcome! I wasn't able to confirm this hypothesis with a user yet but it would explain why it happens across so many different device types, versions and regions, and why it's such a relatively rare phenomenon. If you ever find proof for it, let me know!