# Is it impossible to install incomplete apk from google play Android App Bundle and share it to others?

Tags: android, apk

I got a problem which is similar with [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52469914/app-sometimes-crashes-with-resourcesnotfoundexception-after-switching-to-androi/52474885#52474885). Some users report errors of Unable to find resource ID #0x7f0801be, but the id is actually not in the resource list when checking the apk. Since the SHA signature of users' apk is correct, it seems to be impossible that these users download their app from other place that may repack it.

Would it be that somebody install the app from google play store with aab format, but not completely installed, leading the missing of some resources, and shared the apk to someone else, and didn't change the SHA signature meanwhile? Thanks for any commits!