# Vector image NotFoundException

Tags: android-drawable

In the combat application, I ran into a problem on devices: Xiaomi, Redmi, POCO:

```
Binary XML file line #25 in app:layout/fragment_file_picker: Binary XML 
file line #25 in ru.jcat.jcat:layout/fragment_file_picker: Error 
inflating class <unknown>
Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #25 in 
app/fragment_file_picker: Error inflating class <unknown>
```

On line 25 there is a vector image
I can't reproduce it myself.
I read that this is because of problems with the APK, if they are distributed on the Internet:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/52474885/590947.

But the problem is that I do not openly distribute the APK. I upload the APK only to: Ru Store, NashStore, Huawei Store. In the aab play market.
Has anyone encountered? How did they decide what they were doing?

I tried to reproduce the problem on my devices - it didn't help.
I also tried the `extractor apk`, as a result, where the application was installed, too, everything is ok.

Where there is a difference in pixel density, the APK is simply not installed.
But unfortunately I don't have Xiaomi, Redmi, POCO devices.