# Verify non-Google Play app installs using Play core library

Tags: android, crash, android-app-bundle, sideloading, google-play-core

**Some context:** Most of us may have faced this `ResourceNotFoundException` when we migrated to **Android app bundle** release method. It is evident that the issue is because of Side-loading the app. [Reference here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50471888/android-app-bundle-introduces-resource-not-found-crash-in-android-app)

Google recently announced [solution](https://developer.android.com/guide/app-bundle/sideload-check) to this problem. Using play core library we can identify whether the app is side-loaded or not (Identifies the missing split apks). If the app is side-loaded it shows "**Installation failed**" popup and redirects to play store, where user can properly install the app via the Google Play store.

**Problem:** Everything works fine until the installation of missing split apks from play store. Now when I relaunch the app, it immediately crashes with an error saying.

> Default FirebaseApp is not initialised in this process

**Note:** Directly downloading the app from play store works perfectly fine without any crash. The crash happens only when the app re-downloads because of side loading issue.

**Code:**
Project's `build.gradle`:

```
buildscript {
 dependencies {
  classpath 'com.android.tools.build:bundletool:0.9.0'
 }
}
```

App module's `build.gradle`:

```
 implementation 'com.google.android.play:core:1.6.1'
```

Class that extends Application:

```
 public void onCreate() {
    if (MissingSplitsManagerFactory.create(this).disableAppIfMissingRequiredSplits()) {
        // Skip app initialization.
        return;
    }
    super.onCreate();
    .....
 }
```

Any help would be really great.

Comment: Could you detail what you mean by "The crash happens only when the app re-downloads because of side loading issue". What actions do you perform?

Comment: @Pierre which means, when I install side-loaded app, play core library identifies the app is side-laded and shows the popup saying "installation failed" and redirects to play store to install missing split apks. When I install the missing split apks from Play store and now if I run the apk, it crashes with the above said error.

Comment: The app needs to be uninstalled and re-installed.

Comment: @Pierre That's right. This is how it should be. But when the popup redirects to play store, we see two options "Uninstall" & "Update". People will choose "Update". We cannot expect people who have side-loaded the app will uninstall and reinstall. This has to be forced somewhere or the better approach to be implemented.

Comment: I think you may see "Update" in your case because there is actually a newer version of the app available. We are working on improvements though, yes.

Comment: I was testing this feature on a latest version. So, No. There wasn't any new version released. Thanks.

Comment: Interesting. We're working on a better behaviour which should address this.

Comment: When can we expect the improvements @Pierre?

Comment: Hey @NaveenTP I had written the same steps as per your question but I am getting errors like : (Unable to install, Package not found...on different devices)
Steps: Upload an .abb in internal test 
2) install it in high resolution device
3) shared this apk to low resolution devices via shareIT (app)
4) Getting installation errors.

I have not written any split code or any thing like that in module. They are simple modules.

Comment: Hi @Pierre, with play core v1.6.3, this issue is still exists. Any work around at least?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have solved this issue with the latest version of Play core library:

**App module's build.gradle:**

```
implementation "com.google.android.play:core:1.7.2"
```

Other implementation remains same.

**A class that extends Application:**

```
public void onCreate() {
 if (MissingSplitsManagerFactory.create(this).disableAppIfMissingRequiredSplits()) {
    // Skip app initialization.
    return;
 }
 super.onCreate();
 .....
}
```

**How to test:**

- A better way to test it properly is to release the app bundle with these above fixes in play store internal test channel (Add yourself as a tester).
- Simulate installing invalid apks - Use bundletool to get `.apks` file out of bundle, extract it and install base_master.apk using adb command 
  `adb install base_master.apk`.
- Launch the app, you should see "Installation failed" dialog and it redirects to Play store, clicking on Update, play store will install the missing apks.
- Launching the app should work properly by now.

Hope this helps

Comment: This method is now deprecated

Comment: @marticztn do you know if there is a replacement?