# What would happen on installing app that was uploaded with app bundles from back up on new device with different configuration?

Tags: android, android-app-bundle

I uploaded my app using the Android app bundle tool, which to my understanding creates several APKs (.aab files) for each device configuration with the corresponding resource files.
Now lets say I get a new phone with different resolution and install all my previous apps from backup, will it keep the same .aab file from the previous device just as it keeps the shared preferences? meaning the wrong image sizes ? Or will the resources not be found causing bugs such as

```
 - Caused by android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #15:
   Error inflating class ImageView

 - Caused by android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x7f080263
```

I know these crashes can be occur by sideloading the app ([Android App Bundle introduces Resource Not found crash in Android app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50471888/android-app-bundle-introduces-resource-not-found-crash-in-android-app)), is this the same case?

Comment: I can't follow with the "SIM backup". The SIM card doesn't store any app information. The standard "google-way" is to just to automatically re-download the apps from play store on a new phone, if backup functionality was enabled. Not sure if this is true for a direct USB-backup transfer from one phone to another.

This said however, Google Play Store automatically downloads new resources if the configuration changes. e.g. if you change the language of your phone.

Comment: thank you, but it does keep the same shared preferences from the previous device ?

Comment: The backup functionality, including shared preferences should be not affected. Shared preferences are the same for all device types.

Comment: @Alexander your comment should be answer :)