# NotFoundException for icon resources on Honor devices

Tags: android, google-play-console

Last week (since 17.3) we started to get lots of crashes on Honor devices after users update to the latest build. Crashes happen at start and look like:

```
Exception android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x7f080562   
at android.content.res.ResourcesImpl.getValueForDensity (ResourcesImpl.java:355)   
at android.content.res.Resources.getDrawableForDensity (Resources.java:1069)   
at android.content.res.Resources.getDrawable (Resources.java:1009)
```

It's an icon png resource, we have it for l-, m-, h-, xh-, xxh- and xxxhdpi resolutions. There were no changes to it or to correlated code.
Even app icon for launcher disappears - Android default icon is used.

Some details:

- only Honor devices; the most frequent are Honor 50, Honor 50 Lite, Honor X8, Honor 70
- tried on the same device and OS build as in a crash report: didn't reproduce - so it's not device or system build specific (or there is some complicated correlation)
- some users say that reinstall helps but next day they get the same error

So we think that it may be some app market issue, but we have no concrete hypotheses.

Does someone face the same issue?

Comment: Hi Pavel, we got the same issue with our application in Southeast Asia. Quick question, Does your team also publish the app in Huawei App Gallery?

Comment: Hi @MrMike, we do periodically, but we haven't published it last month.

Comment: We deployed new app version (with no correlated fixes) and see no such crashes anymore ‍♂️

Comment: Yeah, after deploying the new app version seem to fix the issue for our case as well

Answer (score 1):

Looks like it was a one-time bug: have no such issues since the new release.

Comment: I concur. Seems resolved on its own after we released another app bundle release

Answer (score 0):

We have similar findings from our Crashlytics logs.

The issue started to surface around 7th March.

Impacted devices are Honor X9a 5G, Honor 50, Honor 50 Lite and they are between Android 11 and Android 12.

I believe it has to do with us using app bundle and Google misconfigured play store that causes the right drawables to miss out in the user's final download package ([as explained in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73742600/resourcesnotfoundexception-drawable-missing-name-with-resource-id/74164807#74164807))