# How can I padding right hamburger button in Android Toolbar?

Tags: android, android-toolbar

How can I padding left to right a hamburger button inside Android's Toolbar from 1 to 2?

[image]

Comment: I think you need to align it to the right, not to add padding .. as padding will differ from a device to another according to the supported screen width.

Comment: @Zain We can use  "android:gravity="end|center_vertical"" in toolbar?

Comment: Yes but in this case you'll be using a custom toolbar for the actionbar

Comment: @yes I understand, tnx so so much to inform me :)

Answer (score 0):

For AppBarLayout and Toolbar you can use:

```
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay"
        android:layoutDirection="rtl">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />


</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
```

Comment: do u understand question?