# Reduce apk size android

Tags: android, apk, android-proguard

I am facing a problem with app size in android.

The scenario is,

I developed my android app in Android Studio 2.0 and the size of apk was 23 MB.

After that, I upgraded my IDE to android studio 2.2 and with little code modification the size of apk boosted to 51 MB.

I tried with prorogued and Lint but no advantage.

Can Someone help me to tackle the issue.

Comment: Use the APK Analyzer in Android Studio 2.2 to determine where your space is going. Nobody else is going to be able to help you, since we do not have your APK.

Comment: check your resources and remove if not required then tiny your resource with https://tinypng.com/

Answer (score 3):

1) Replace all of Images,Icons with vector drawable

2) Turn on pro guard like following
goto build.gradleapp level

and put these lines

**shrinkResources true

minifyEnabled true**

3) Remove unused classes,drawable and methods and strings
and use LINT's private method analyser which reduces method count

[JAVA's Hidden cost](https://realm.io/news/360andev-jake-wharton-java-hidden-costs-android/)

4) In android studio 2.2 and above they have added **apk analyser** tool in **Build** menu. Use that to analyse APk

5) if app size goes beyond 100mb use feature called split apk.
there are two methods of spliting apk
ABI and Density Splits

Answer (score 1):

Do this changes in your `build.gradle(Module:app)` file. It decreases the apk size almost (40-50)%.

```
android {
// Other settings

  buildTypes {
      release {
        minifyEnabled true
        shrinkResources true
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
      }
  }
}
```

It reduces the size of `classes.dex` files and `res folder`.

It is recommended to that you should use `webp` file format instead of `BMP, JPG, PNG` for better compression.

For reference, you can use: https://developer.android.com/studio/write/convert-webp.html

For more details on apk compression you can refer:

https://developer.android.com/topic/performance/reduce-apk-size.html

[https://medium.com/how-you-can-decrease-application-size](https://medium.com/@kevalpatel2106/how-you-can-decrease-application-size-by-60-in-only-5-minutes-47eff3e7874e)

Answer (score 1):

Points to reduce APK size:

```
Make sure to do it

1. Use vector drawable
2. Use xml drawable to create simple view
3. Rotate images using xml drawable to reuse (eg. in case of arrow buttons)
4. Create drawable through code
5. Use aaptOptions { cruncherEnabled = false } to compress images
6. Use webP format for large images
7. Avoid enumerations and use @IntDef annotation
8. Use shrinkResources true in gradle to remove unused resources
9. Use resConfig “en” in gradle to remove other localization
```

Answer (score 0):

```
android {
    // Other settings

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            shrinkResources true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}
```

`shrinkResources true` will not include the images from resources which your using in the final apk

hope this will help you!