# APK size is too large

Tags: android, apk

[image]

As you can see the res folder is of 2.2 MB only still the APK size is 17 MB. The lib folder is of 11 MB so I think something is wrong with this. Anybody can suggest me what's wrong with this so that my APK size can be reduced.

Comment: you can enable **minify** your code using gradle and also shrink your resources. https://developer.android.com/studio/build/shrink-code.html

Comment: whats your `minifyEnabled` status ? runProguard

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25101534/reducing-android-app-apk-size

Comment: yes minify and shrinkResources both are true

Comment: I am using proguard too

Comment: `... the res folder is of 2.2 MB only ...` But the `lib` folder is over 24 MB. Just to say.

Comment: I got the issue, actually there was 1 library which was increasing APK size to 10 MB

Comment: Well, you see: my previous comment said it all.

Comment: Thanks all for the help, I know it was a silly question but still I learned a lot from this. Thanks again..

Answer (score 2):

**1st**

```
android {
    // Other settings

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            shrinkResources true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}
```

**2nd**

- Reduce Resource Count and Size.
- Remove Unused Resources.

**3rd**

Compress the .jpg files as much as possible, You can use [TinyPng](https://tinypng.com/)

Hope this solves your problem

Comment: and if you still need more try to use `proguard-android-optimize.txt` https://developer.android.com/studio/build/shrink-code.html

Answer (score 2):

you are using some native code inside your application(your own app code or maybe the libraries), hence the **libs** folder and the **.so**(shared object) files are getting generated.you can't escape from this. lol.  anyway you can rectify this problem by **splitting your apk for different CPU-architectures**. open up your app-level build.gradle and paste this code. you'll get different apks for different  CPU-architectures.

```
splits {
    abi {
        enable true // enable ABI split feature to create one APK per ABI
        universalApk true //generate an additional APK that targets all the ABIs
    }
}
// map for the version code
project.ext.versionCodes = ['armeabi':1, 'armeabi-v7a':2, 'arm64-v8a':3, 'mips':5, 'mips64':6, 'x86':8, 'x86_64':9]

android.applicationVariants.all { variant ->
    // assign different version code for each output
    variant.outputs.each { output ->
        output.versionCodeOverride =
                project.ext.versionCodes.get(output.getFilter(com.android.build.OutputFile.ABI), 0) * 10000000 + android.defaultConfig.versionCode
    }
}
```

later on, you can upload these apks on play store with particular one architecture only. for more information, refer this great [blog](https://blog.be-bound.com/apk-split-tutorial/) and this [blog](https://ph0b.com/android-abis-and-so-files/)