# Does android jetpack make app size larger (for < 3MB apk) after converting my app into Jetpack?

Tags: android, size, android-jetpack

I am building light-weight app for delivering service-data.

I tried to looked at [Reducing android app (apk) size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25101534/reducing-android-app-apk-size) asked by Vivek Warde. Its looks similar problem but its not that i m just trying to use Jetpack to my application so that i can use feature of live data and other animation stuff.

As i looked futher in Android Documentation on ProGuard on app size matter but it says [here](https://developer.android.com/topic/performance/reduce-apk-size#minimize)

> Note: ProGuard can clean up some unnecessary code imported with a library, but it can't remove a library's large internal dependencies.

So i was doubt that app size get increase.

Comment: Step 1 in build.gradle turn minifyEnabled false into true and also make Apk bndle to reduce your apk size

Comment: I had 5 Mb apk and now it is 2 Mb by following these steps

Comment: did you use jetpack in you app ? @LokikSoni